# Agregar Headers a csv - python

Tags: python

Teniendo este código ¿Cómo puedo agregarle 'Headers' manualmente al ejecutar esta *función*? Con este código solo se agregan los headers que están en la DataBase. Gracias

```
def export():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Example.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Table1")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    csv_path = "output.csv"
    with open(csv_path, "w", newline="") as csv_file:        
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        # Write headers.
        csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])
        # Write data.
        csv_writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer, podrías explicarlo mejor?

Comment: El código jala una tabla de la DataBase y crea. un documento con todas las columnas y filas de dicha tabla. Mi idea es poner codigo para agregar 3 columnas más. @Christian

Comment: 3 columnas aparte de las que hay en tu bd?

Comment: S9lo agregas las columnas o también  los datos?

Comment: Exactamente 3 columnas aparte de las que ya existen.  Por el momento solo las columnas.

Comment: OK en un momento te doy una respuesta, perooo... de donde salen las 3 columnas extras?

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda hermano. Solo necesito agregar las columnas es decir, no importa el nombre ni nada, unicamente necesito agregarlas. En la DataBase existen 7 columnas, con estas 3 nuevas ya serian 10 en total

Comment: Una pregunta, que retorna `[i[0] for i in cur.description]`??

Comment: Tengo claro que eso es para el orden de asignación de las columnas y sus nombres

Comment: podías hacer un `print` del resultado y decirme que es lo que retorna, ya iba a publicar la respuesta, pero todo depende del resultado de eso

Comment: me sale un "49"

Comment: `res = [i[0] for i in cur.description]` y luego haces `print(res)`, no creo que simplemente salga 49

Comment: Lo estaba haciendo mal disculpa, salen los nombres de las columnas ['ID', 'Nombre', 'Direccion' .......]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para el manejo de archivos csv recomiendo pandas, este módulo te permite manejar grandes cantidades de datos de forma fácil y tiene varias cosas que de seguro te serán útiles.

**instalación**

```
pip install pandas
```

En pandas se manejan los *DataFrames* que son un tipo de dato que nos permite hacer operaciones, algo parecido a lo que se hace en Excel pero en código. Para crear *DataFrames* existen diversas formas, ya sea con listas diccionarios, archivos excel, csv, etc. Para este caso lo haremos con diccionarios. Una vez teniendo el *DataFrame* podremos exportarlo como un archivo csv y listo!

```py
import pandas as pd

#cambinamos lo de tu DB con 3 columnas
res = [i[0] for i in cur.description]+["Columna","columnaa2","columna3"]
data = {k:[] for k in res} #convertimos a diccionario

#convertimos a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#exportamos como csv
df.to_csv("archivo.csv")
```

Peroooo.... existe una forma más simplificada de hacer todo esto, en un comentario especificaste que solo quieres colocar las columnas asi que podemos optar por esto **solo si** quieres poner solo los *headers*. Al crear nuestro *DataFrame* con `pd.DataFrame()` el primer argumento serán los datos que contendrá y también se le puede especificar las columnas que contendrá en su parámetro `columns` lo que, al exportar, se traduce a sus *headers*.

```py
import pandas as pd

#obtenemos los datos y agregamos 3 mas
res = [i[0] for i in cur.description]+["Columna","columnaa2","columna3"]

#creamos un dataframe sin datos y con las columnas correspondientes
df = pd.DataFrame({}, columns=res)

#esportamos
df.to_csv("archivo.csv")
```

Comment: Excelente hermano, tarde en comprobarlo por la instalacion de pandas pero ya quedó. Gracias es lo que buscaba